# Formatting Date with PHP from weird twitter format

Tags: php, datetime, date-conversion

Through the twitter API I was able to get the datetime of when something was tweeted

```
Jul 25 17:42:55 +0000 2013
```

Now, in PHP, how do I get that into standard unix:

```
2013-6-25 17:42:55
```

I'm not to sure on anything to deal with datetime but I think there is an easier way to do this rather than having to parse through and change things with `str_replace` and `substr`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/class.datetime.php) class, specifically the static [`createFromFormat()`](http://www.php.net/manual/datetime.createfromformat.php) method

```
$dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('M j H:i:s P Y', 'Jul 25 17:42:55 +0000 2013');
echo $dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Working example - http://codepad.viper-7.com/gLdEll

Comment: Twitter feed stamps look like "Mon Sep 08 15:19:11 +0000 2014", correct format for these is $d = \DateTime::createFromFormat('D M d H:i:s P Y', (string)$x->created_at);

Answer (score 8):

Simply pass it through `strtotime`. Note that this includes a timezone +0000 so the time will translate relative to your timezone also.

```
<?php
$date = "Jul 25 17:42:55 +0000 2013";
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($date));
```

Comment: This also works I suppose, I got strtotime to work, but it wasn't suiting my needs. Thank you for your input though

Comment: Also, you probably want `H`, not `h`

Comment: With this, Tue Jan 27 21:53:43 +0000 2015 gets translated as 2015-01-27 15:53:43. The hour is not same.

Comment: @Jeremy time gets translated relative to your timezone. please read my post :-)